# About stack and counter

Tags: assembly

I hope you all are doing well.

I have a question about counter CX register and stack.

Let's suppose I have a CX=500, it means counter in CX will run atleast 500 times .

If I push this CX register on stack,the value of 500 from it will be copied to stack and original value of 500 will remain in CX.

If we use this instruction to move value 20 in CX register .

"mov CX,20".

It will move 20 in CX register .

Will the new value in CX register be 20 as value 500 in it will be over written by 20?

Pls correct me If I am wrong .

Thanks

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Until you pop cx back off the stack, then it will be 500 again.